# How incorporate third party libraries like Matomo/Google Analytics to Apache NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm looking for a way to include in Apache NiFi, JS clients like Matomo/Google Analytics, without change the source code.

Comment: incorporate meaning - consume data from them

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the UI doesn't have any support for this sort of behavior. I also don't see us integrating support for it any time soon because these sort of analytics don't really make any sense for 99% of our users.

Comment: I used the "matomo/google analytics" as a example, I need put a code for NPS/CES.

Comment: Looking on the code, I not find a way to do that. So, by now, I think it's not possible. Perhaps using an API Gateway. Thanks Mike.